# Windows x64 registry creating my key on Wow6432node and not working properly

Tags: windows, registry, 64-bit

My program is trying to create an key on the

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Shared Tools\MSCONFIG\startupreg\test\
```

but instead the key is created on the

```
HKLM\Wow6432node\Software\Microsoft\Shared Tools\MSCONFIG\startupreg\test\
```

and don't work properly... Why? How can I solve it?

Comment: What does "don't work properly" mean?

Comment: The program doesnt apper on the msconfig for startup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Registry redirection is on, because you are running a 32-bit program. If you switch to 64-bit, you will not have this redirection.

Answer (score 0):

[Turn off registry redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384129(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: how can I do it on Python with _winreg?

Comment: Don't know, don't care, you should have tagged your question "Python".  Most likely you'll need to call the Windows API directly, if you didn't feel the programming language was important enough to even mention that I assume you're able to translate any solution we give you into your language.